# Change body background with data-theme attribute on click with React

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to change the theme in an app using the `data` attribute and then changing the CSS variables according to the different `data-theme` values.

In the `App` component, I check if the user has a default theme set, and use that to set new theme on click

```
import "./styles.css";
import useLocalStorage from "use-local-storage";

export default function App() {
  // Check user set theme mode...
  const defaultDark = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches;

  // Create theme mode state...
  const [theme, setTheme] = useLocalStorage(
    "theme",
    defaultDark ? "dark" : "light"
  );

  // Handle on click from the theme switcher...
  const clickHandler = () => {
    const newTheme = theme === "light" ? "dark" : "light";

    setTheme(newTheme);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App" data-theme={theme}>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button onClick={() => clickHandler()}>Dark Mode</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

In the `styles.css` I set the different variables to define the theme

```
/* Set the dark mode variables... */
[data-theme="dark"] {
  --background: black;
  --title-text: white;
  --desc-text: grey;
}

/* Set the light mode variables... */
[data-theme="light"] {
  --background: white;
  --title-text: black;
  --desc-text: grey;
}

/* Page Styles... */
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: var(--background);
}

/*The rest of the CSS...*/
```

The rest of the elements work fine as they are wrapped in an element that has the `data-theme` attribute. However, the `body` is not wrapped with the `data-theme` attribute, so there is no change in the `body` background. In this example, I used `.App` but I would like to change the `body` instead. Is there a way to wrap the `body` in the `data-theme` attribute in React?

Here is the link to the full code in CodeSandbox
[Full code on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/change-theme-x6bj8x?file=/src/styles.css:0-349)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about wrap App with div.body them pass data-theme into .body instead and make div.body cover body

```
<div className='body' data-theme={theme}>
    <div className='App'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wrapping the App with the `.body` lets me manipulate the `className` but not the `body` tag. Is it possible to manipulate the actual `body` tag using the `data-theme` attribute?

Comment: cause `div#root` is inside body tag and react will render inside `#root`, so i dont think we cant reach `body` tag, except using `document.querySelector` and pass `data-theme` by `setAttribute`, but it's so weird while we using react.

Comment: I understand that now, thanks